# Flash Game ArgumentError: Error #2025 removeChild

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to get the bat character to remove the jack/2/3 child(s) in my game here, but I keep getting the ArgumentError: Error #2025. I understand that I may be removing a child twice, perhaps? I'm looking around and I'm not really experienced in this stuff so I'm having a hard time understanding what needs to be done to fix this issue. Can someone tell me what needs to be done with my code specifically, please?

```
var jack:pumpkin = new pumpkin();
var jack2:pumpkin = new pumpkin();
var jack3:pumpkin = new pumpkin();
var score:Number = 0;

scoreBox.text = String(score);

addChild(jack);
jack.x = 125;
jack.y = 285;

addChild(jack2);
jack2.x = 270;
jack2.y = 310;

addChild(jack3);
jack3.x = 445;
jack3.y = 285;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveLeft);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveRight);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveDown);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, moveUp);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, bump);

function moveLeft(e:KeyboardEvent):void {

if (e.keyCode == 37) {
        bat.x -= 5;
    }
}
function moveRight(e:KeyboardEvent):void {

if (e.keyCode == 39) {
        bat.x += 5;
    }
}
function moveDown(e:KeyboardEvent):void {

if (e.keyCode == 40) {
        bat.y += 5;
    }
}
function moveUp(e:KeyboardEvent):void {

if (e.keyCode == 38) {
        bat.y -= 5;
    }
}

function bump(e:KeyboardEvent):void {

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumpIt);

    function bumpIt(e:Event):void {

        if (bat.hitTestObject(jack)) {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumpIt);
            removeChild(jack);
            score++;
            scoreBox.text = String(score);
        }
        if (bat.hitTestObject(jack2)) {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumpIt);
            removeChild(jack2);
            score++;
            scoreBox.text = String(score);
        }
        if (bat.hitTestObject(jack3)) {
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumpIt);
            removeChild(jack3);
            score++;
            scoreBox.text = String(score);
        }
    }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Due to the nested `bumpit()` event handler, on every key up you're adding another enter frame event if your hit-test has no collision.

- On `KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP`, event handler calls `bump()` which adds an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener that will call `bumpIt()`.

  - If `bat.hitTestObject()` is true, you remove `Event.ENTER_FRAME`.
  - If not, you still have the `Event.ENTER_FRAME` listener firing `bumpIt()` every frame.

So, every key up you're potentially adding another frame handler.

If ten key up events occurred and none of them hit test your objects, you are now calling `bumpIt` ten times a frame.

If you need to hit test on key up, just put the logic there:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, bump);

function bump(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    if (bat.hitTestObject(jack)) { /* ... */ }
}
```

Or, if you're tracking an animation sequence after key up, maybe add some state variable, such as:

```
var isFlying:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, bump);

function bump(e:KeyboardEvent):void {
    // If bat is already flying, don't add another frame handler
    if (isFlying)
        return;

    // Otherwise, indicate bat is now flying and add frame handler
    isFlying = true;

    stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumpIt);
}
```

Then, if your hit-test works and you remove your frame handler, reset the state variable:

```
stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumpIt);
isFlying = false;
```

Another solution is to remove the nested handlers.  Because you have nested `bumpIt()` inside `bump()`, you are seeing cumulative firing of callbacks due to scope:

```
function bump():void {
    function bumpIt():void { /* ... */ }
}
```

Simply promote `bumpIt()`:

```
function bump():void { /* ... */ }
function bumpIt():void { /* ... */ }
```

Comment: uneducated answer, you can't add the same listener multiple times. You can call this: "stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, bumpIt);" a thousand times you'll still only have one listener. Voted down for misleading answer.

Comment: @BotMaster, If you take the time to read the question, you'll note that `bumpIt()` is nested inside `bump()` - the way scope works will create cumulative handlers.

Comment: @BotMaster Actually, thanks for pointing that out - I've updated my answer to better clarify the nested function, as it's easy to miss now that I look at this question again.